# NGINX Connection Refused After Ubuntu 16 Update

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, drupal, server

After updating Ubuntu to 16, I have been sorting through some errors I have come across. The website worked fine before the upgrade (It is running Drupal). Nginx -t returns the syntax is okay and the test was successful. Recovering from a backup also does not fix the problem.

Below is the Nginx conf

```
server {
server_name example.com;
root /usr/share/nginx/html/drupal/;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
    allow 192.168.0.0/16;
    deny all;
}

location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
    return 403;
}
location ~ sites/default/files/.*php {
    return 403;
}

location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
    return 403;
}

# Allow "Well-Known URIs" as per RFC 5785
location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
    allow all;
}

# Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
# period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
# as Subversion or Git to store control files.
location ~ (^|/)\. {
    return 403;
}

location / {
     try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; 
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
}

location ~* /sites/.*/files/styles/ {
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

# Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}
}
```

My error log is displaying the below

```
[error] 14933#14933: *1320 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 11.111.11.111, server: website.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "website.com"
```

curl -i website.com returns

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 03 Oct 2017 02:21:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 182
Connection: keep-alive
```

Nginx status returns the below

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
enabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-10-02 22:07:47 EDT; 18min ago
Process: 25609 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 25039 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s 
reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 25612 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; 
(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 25611 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 25615 (nginx)
CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
       ├─25615 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; 
master_process on
       └─25616 nginx: worker process                           

Oct 02 22:07:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web 
server and a reverse proxy server.
Oct 02 22:07:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web 
server and a reverse proxy server...
Oct 02 22:07:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Oct 02 22:07:47 ubuntu-1gb systemd[1]: Started A high performance web 
server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Service PHP5-FPM Status returns the below

```
● php5-fpm.service - LSB: starts php5-fpm
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/php5-fpm; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Mon 2017-10-02 21:00:13 EDT; 1h 28min ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 24934 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/php5-fpm stop (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 25598 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/php5-fpm reload (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 24936 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/php5-fpm start (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 02 21:03:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: starts php5-fpm.
Oct 02 21:03:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: starts php5-fpm.
Oct 02 22:05:36 ubuntu systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: starts php5-fpm.
Oct 02 22:05:36 ubuntu systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: starts php5-fpm.
Oct 02 22:06:30 ubuntu systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: starts php5-fpm.
Oct 02 22:06:30 ubuntu systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: starts php5-fpm.
Oct 02 22:07:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: starts php5-fpm.
Oct 02 22:07:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: starts php5-fpm.
Oct 02 22:07:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: starts php5-fpm.
Oct 02 22:07:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: starts php5-fpm.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: maybe conflict with apache2 ?

Comment: Can you  open some "static" file, i.e. some picture?

Comment: @MilanG Yes I can open photos

Comment: Seems like Nginx is not configured properly. Check this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/317393/connect-failed-111-connection-refused-while-connecting-to-upstream

Comment: @MilanG thanks i'll try that after work to see if I can sort it out

Comment: @MilanG appears to only really have the difference of the listen directive, when I add that in, I get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED page and nothing written to my database. Any ideas of where I can look to fix that? Anything is greatly appreciated as I am quite stuck